# How to determine API url from code in API Gateway Deployments

Tags: java, spring

Our application is deployed behind nginx and Kong API Gateway. The backend is behind the firewall. Only nginx and kong are exposed to the outside world. Please refer to the attached screenshot.

Our code needs to call a third party async api that accepts a callback-url. How do we generate the callback-url such that the third party service calls back our service via kong?

Without the firewall, nginx and kong setup we had the following code that was working so far but this doesn't work now. It generates the url as below http://kong-server-name:8000/my-spring-app/api/v1/callback which is incorrect. The server-name and port number are referring to kong but rest of the path is the context path of my-spring-app.

```java
String baseUrl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequestUri(request)
                    .replacePath(null)
                    .build()
                    .toUriString();
                    
callbackUrl = baseUrl + this.contextPath + EndPointReferer.CALLBACK;
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is the above URL provided the correct URL that will reach your application. If so, the only thing that changed in your deployment is the firewall addition. Have you checked if the firewall port is open to allow the call to your application from Kong?

Comment: No this is not the correct url. The correct url would  http://kong-server-name:8000/prod/api/v1/callback since thats the path I have configured in kong. For the same app I have multiple paths configured in kong-config file depending on the environment - dev, test or prod.